# Ensure a unique policy ID for a "time before" type minting policy

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nft

Let's suppose I am starting an NFT project, and I choose to use a time-lock based policy script.  For example, the policy is enabled until some slot in the future.

E.g, here's the Hosky Cash Grab NFT script, which is open until slot `112500819`.

```
{
  "type": "all",
  "scripts": [
    {
      "keyHash": "4d04380dcb9fbad5aff8e2f4e19394ef4e5e11b37932838f01984a12",
      "type": "sig"
    },
    {
      "slot": 112500819,
      "type": "before"
    }
  ]
}
```

When you calculate the Blake2B hash of the policy script serialized to bytes, you get a policy ID, e.g. `a5bb0e5bb275a573d744a021f9b3bff73595468e002755b447e01559`.

If another project happens to choose the same slot for their required-time-before policy and generates the same script or they simply choose to use the same script, won't they also have the same policy ID? This seems like a bad outcome, since I assume that querying the NFT assets minted under the policy ID could potentially show NFTs from another project.  Am I correct about this?

As a related question, I understand that projects may register a policy ID for their project in a github repo [Cardano-NFTs/policyIDs](https://github.com/Cardano-NFTs/policyIDs).  What protection or value does registering offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will also have to come up with the same keyHash to have the same policy ID, and that is virtually impossible.